# Single Sign On with Okta session

Tags: java, single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

I have multiple web applications running in different domains. Okta is the identity/auth provider for all these applications. After integrating with Okta in one of the application (following the Java example provided in Okta documentation), a new cookie (**sid**) is being created in Okta domain (https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/sessions/).

How do I use this to SSO into other web application. What is the best approach to allow access to other application without prompting login credentials again?

Do I need to invoke **getCurrentSession** API in every application and redirect to login page only if the API response is 404 (as per doc, getCurrentSession will retrieve the current active session based on the Okta cookie).

Please share thoughts.

Comment: If you're using OIDC, your existing session on Okta should translate to your 2nd app too. That is, if you log in to the first one, then navigate to the 2nd one and try to log in, you'll be logged in automatically.

Comment: Yes, I am using OIDC. The session id cookie is getting created in Okta domain, after doing authentication in my app1. Question is, how can I do auth on my app2. Do I need to explicitly call any API (or redirect) so that Okta can validate the session id cookie and return authenticated response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you integrate your apps: redirect to Okta or using Okta widget. If you do redirect it's pretty much guaranteed to have zero issues authenticating in your second app, as your redirect for second app will send `sid` cookie back to Okta, which was set while authenticating with your first app.

With widget things may become bit complicated, as it depends on 3rd party cookies. `okta-auth-js` GitHub repo has some examples on how you can check if session exists with okta, when you trying to authenticate a user. Check https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#third-party-cookies

Comment: Tried the first approach and is working. All the app should redirect to Okta and allow login if auth was successful, otherwise show the login page.

Comment: This is a long shot.. asking years later. I can't seem to figure out the first part "sid cookie, which was set while authenticating with your first app" - is this something that okta handles? I am authenticating successfully with a saml auth request, but I don't see an sid cookie created.

Comment: OIE now handles that through a different cookie, also make sure that you are on the same site as Okta, otherwise you'll be falling under 3rd party cookie policy of your browser